# Animated matplotlib plot, Y axis points are not arranged properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

i'm currently writing a script in python, the script is used to test
DNS response time.
 im using matplotlib to display the data graphically but as the graph updates the points are not being order in the right way, i tried anything that i could
and i just cant figure out what is wrong with my function.
im adding the animate function and the picture of the graph.
fyi FuncAnimation calls animate with generator function which every iteration yields different URL (between google and facebook), and than calls a function that brings new DNS response times to a dictionary which supply the values for the animate function.

`def animate(url):

```
    # The Y axis will represent the request/response time, while the
    plot_dict = master_dict[url]

    # x_val is a time string, format is "%H:%M:%S", y_val is a float.
    # in the array x_val turnin to numpy.string, y_val to a numpy.float64
    x_val = plot_dict[TIME]
    y_val = plot_dict[DNS]

    point = np.array([[x_val, y_val]])

    if 'google' in url:
        graph_list[0] = np.append(graph_list[0], point, axis=0)
        print graph_list[0].T
        x, y = graph_list[0].T
        return plt.plot(x, y, color='g')

    else:
        graph_list[1] = np.append(graph_list[1], point, axis=0)
        x, y = graph_list[1].T
        print graph_list[1].T
        return plt.plot(x, y, color='r')`
```

graph_list[0] is a 2D numpy array of the google points, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLb8s.png) is facebook, and everytime i get a new point Iadd it to its array

[image]

Comment: This happens if you're plotting strings, are you sure y_val is a float? Also please provide some data.

Comment: As pxe said: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help SO users helping you.

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question here? But mind that the code is not runnable. See [mcve].